# form data and class objects

Tags: c#

EDIT::
This might be simple for some but right now it has me confused. I am working on a project and when the submit button is pressed,create either a person or an employee based on the above checkbox. Put all of the form data into the class object using either the constructor or properties. Display all of the class information using the ToString method and a messagebox.

My question is::
When it is asking when the submit button is pressed, create a person or an employee based on the above checkbox.Would I use what is above the checkbox or below.

Also to put all of the form data into the class object using either the constructors or properties. I'm Not to sure how to do this.

Display all of the class information using a ToString and a messagebox. I understand how to do a messagebox but not with a ToString.

Now I already have two classes and those names are Members and Employees. Under the Members I have Name, Age, and COB. Under the employees I have Salary and JobTitle. The only time that the salary and jobtitle comes up if the user check the checkbox that says is person employee.

I am sorry if I confuse people I myself is kinda confused with what is being asked. The software I am using is Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Expressed.

The code I have so far don't know if it is right or not:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Members obj = new Members(); <---This is what is I am assuming being asked when
        obj.Name = "";                   its says create either a person or an employee
        obj.Age = "";                    based on the above checkbox.
        obj.COB = "";

        Employess obj1 = new Employess(); <-- here I am trying to put all of the form 
        obj1.Salary = "";                     data into the class object using either
        obj1.JobTitle = "";                   the constructor or properties.




        Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());<--- this is the messagebox I am being asked to do its not all the way done.


    }
```

Comment: Winforms? Webforms? WPF? Windows phone? Silverlight?

Comment: @shan Its unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: Can you please make your question a little clearer so people can help you better? You obviously have some things mixed up; for example, you don't use `Console.WriteLine()` in a Windows Form application, and it's certainly not relevant in showing message boxes. Can you please rephrase what you've done, post the code for each part, and give us the complete assignment?

Comment: Ok I edit to try to explain better for you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I get from your code is you have taken two classes for employees and members and you want to store their information in objects of respective classes based upon your checkbox selection. I suppose you are working in windows forms because you have specified the button_click event.
If that's the case:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(checkbox1_Member.Checked==true)
    {
              Members obj = new Members();
              obj.Name = "";
              obj.Age = "";
              obj.COB = "";
              MessageBox.Show(obj.Name+ " :: " +"obj.Age.ToString());
    }
    else if(checkbox2_Employee.Checked==true)
    {
              Employees obj1 = new Employees();
              obj1.Salary = "";
              obj1.JobTitle = "";             
              MessageBox.Show (obj1.Salary.ToString()+ " ::"+obj.JobTitle.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This part I do believe has nothing to do with the checkbox only when the user hits the submit button.

Comment: I am still not clear with what you are trying to achieve. Are you saying that if the user checks for the checkbox the information for the employee(including member class information) is to be displayed and if the checkbox is unchecked, only the member class information is displayed.

Comment: What I am trying to get is if the submit button is pressed, create either a person or an employee based on the above checkbox. Put all of the form data into the class object using either the constructor or properties. Display all of the class information using ToString method and a messagebox. I already have a checkbox that is the user press that then the salary and jobtitle comes up and the user can enter that information. But if they dont check it then it is not there.

Comment: The above code should work fine for the submit button click event, and if you need that some controls are displayed or enabled when checkbox is checked, you can do that by creating an CheckboxCheckChanged event.

Comment: Errors:The name 'checkbox1_Employess' does not exist in the current context.The name 'checkbox1_Members' does not exist in the current context.The name 'obj' does not exist in the current context .
 
it is also saying newline in constant with this "obj.Age.ToString());

Comment: I figure out the obj tostring one.

Comment: specify the name of your checkbox in place of "checkbox1_Employees".

Comment: Well I got the errors fixed on it but now nothing is coming to the messagebox... Thank you for all your help...

Comment: it is so because you haven't specified any value to the properties of the class :: obj.name="The Name of the person";

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague but let's make a ton of assumptions:

1. You have a checkbox you've renamed to 'checkEmployess'. (I'm not sure if you meant 'employee' but let's just go with it.)
2. You have text boxes on your form for all of the stuff the user has entered with sensible names.
3. All the input is in text at the moment.

So, you need to check whether the checkbox is ticked/checked with an `if` statement and create the correct sort of object:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object dude; // if you use inheritance then this could be of the base class's type

    if (this.checkEmployess.Checked)
    {
        // it's an employess
        Employess employee = new Employess();
        employess.Salary = textSalary.Text; // this copies the value of the control into your object
        employess.JobTitle = textJobTitle.Text; // however for this example we've assumed every control is a text control and your object has only string properties

        dude = employess;
    }
    else
    {
        // it's a member
        Members member = new Members();
        member.Name = textName.Text;
        member.Age = textAge.Text; // this in particular should be made numeric
        member.COB = textCOB.Text;

        dude = member;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(dude);
}
```

That's the basic object creation done. You could add a `ToString` method to these two classes to format their properties for display. (This approach is a bit crude but will work so stick with this for now.)

Improvements you can then make are:

1. Use input controls that are more suitable for the type of input. E.g. numeric controls for numbers, &c.
2. Use object initializers for constructing these objects.
3. Use methods to correctly format these two types of objects for display).